# Visual studio 2017 - copy local false

Tags: visual-studio-2017

i have a class library project targeting net461 in visual studio 2017. and i only want the single dll built.

previously i can set Copy Local to FALSE in the references for assemblies and nuget. but now the option is not there.

how can i build only the single dll file for the class library in visual studio 2017?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio 2017 are you using? I'm using VS2017 RTW and this option is available.